# How do I increase the spacing of the line number margin in vim?

Tags: vim, margin, macvim

I have a problem with my colorscheme in vim:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tinygrab.com](http://new.tinygrab.com/ca56d2c7a8e13f7077012bece6abd90e.png))</sub>

The line numbers are too close to the code. How I can increase the width of the line numbers' right margin?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no option to affect that spacing. I'm surprised you think they're too close - that's the same one-character spacing every vim user has - but I'm aware it's a personal preference. I'd suggest making the numbers a lower contrast to get some aesthetic distance but it looks like you've already done that.

Comment: Why don't you try making it so every line displayed has a space at the beginning of it (giving the appearance of a gap). Just make sure to remove that line on all save commands!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/screen.c#L2220

Looking at the code, it turns to be impossible (without patching the vim, obviously): vim always formats the line numbers to take up the whole available width, leaving just a single space afterwards (the "%*ld " format specifier in the code makes sure of that).

Comment: Why don't rigid vim developers change that? :/

Answer (score 20):

This bothered me, too; I hate having text crammed up against a block of solid color. It makes me claustrophobic.

Here's what I did as a workaround (in MacVim, but I expect the same technique will work elsewhere):

In your preferred colorscheme, set the background color of the line-number column to be the same as the background color for normal text, and the line-number foreground color to something low-contrast and unobtrusive (so it doesn't look like it's part of your normal text). I use white-on-black for normal text, and dark-grey-on-black for the line numbers:

```
hi LineNr  guifg=#505050   guibg=Black
hi Normal  guifg=White     guibg=Black
```

Admittedly, this doesn't fix the problem so much as hide it, but it's worked well for me.

Comment: "claustrophobic" that's the word !  Feel the same here. Good workaround though

Answer (score 15):

You can add the following line in your "~/.vimrc":

`set nuw=6`

Where "6" specfies the width of the column in terms of number of characters. Replace with a smaller or large number as needed. Only works with more recent (>=7?) versions of Vim, I think.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP is asking, it just makes the width of the number column bigger, moving them deeper into your text and thus 'worse'

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: While not answering the question, it helped me do what I wanted to do when I was googling around.

Answer (score 2):

`%left 5`
in the vim terminal (`%` whole document, `left` distance code to linenrs, `0-infinity` distance in monospace (= number of columns))

Comment: that's the correct solution but is there anyway to set it in `init.vim` or `.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to you init.vim file.

```
autocmd VimEnter * :%left 5
```

Comment: this removes the left padding from each line of the file so the formatting gets a little off

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution 2 (ref to [how to change the left margin in gvim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893390/how-to-change-the-left-margin-in-gvim#7894736))

Solution 1 (like `%left 5` )just adds 'spaces' into the code area. I guess it does the same done by the threadstarter ...but it does not the answer the original question.

**Solution 2**: `foldcolumn` does the trick (foldcolumn is the column left from the linenumbers)
In exec mode `:set foldcolumn=12`
If you want to change the color too (like in the ref)
`hi FoldColumn guibg=#003f3f` (in the ref its `FoldColumns`, thats wrong).