# MacVim: how do I set a left gutter (margin) for my buffers?

Tags: vim, macvim

In MacVim the text that I'm editing in all buffers is jammed up hard against the left hand side of the buffer. I find this quite visually jarring, especially if I'm looking at a vertical split.

It looks like there is only one pixel between my text and the window border.

Is there a setting that will allow me to add, say, a character width as a gutter or margin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the left margin in gvim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893390/how-to-change-the-left-margin-in-gvim)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I use line numbering for that reason (`:set number`).  But if you want a margin without the numbers, use:

```
:set foldcolumn=<width>
```

Example:

```
:set foldcolumn=3
```

Comment: Great stuff. Exactly what I needed! Because I've got a dark background, I also discovered how to set that as follows (in case somebody else finds this useful): `highlight FoldColumn guibg=gray14 guifg=white`

Comment: To add to Scott's comment: For Vim in a (black) terminal, one can use   `:highlight FoldColumn ctermbg=0` to turn the foldcolumn black.

Comment: This setting only support up to `9` columns.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a MacVim-specific option, `MMTextInsetLeft`, which can be set with `defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTextInsetLeft VALUE` in a terminal (where `VALUE` is the number of pixels in the left margin. There are also settings for right, top, and bottom margin, see `help macvim-user-defaults` for details.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy:

```
 set foldcolumn=2
 highlight FoldColumn ctermbg=0
 highlight FoldColumn ctermfg=0
```

Comment: ...and if you're wondering why macvim isn't making the margin black, you need `guibg=0`

Comment: This is one of those little things I need to make my graphical vim palatable when transitioning away from other GUI text editors.