# Any way to add additional space after line number in Vim?

Tags: vim, configuration

I am looking for a way to move text further from the line number in Vim. Default settings are to add one space after the line number when using `set number`. I would like to add a bit more. Using `set numberwidth=n` doesn't help, because additional space goes before the line number, not in between the line number and the text itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No native Vim option seems to alter this, but there is an old plugin which could accomplish what you want to achieve called [vimroom](https://mikewest.github.io/vimroom/). It is not actively being maintained and I don't know if it still works with current Vim versions. But [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7FB1.png) makes it look like it is possible to have the line numbers way on the left.

Hopefully this pointer helps you out!

Comment: There was even this guy checking Vim's source code and finding it is fundamentally impossible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2534520/7653320